# Get Field Name Being Deleted From Configuration Updates/Delete Form

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

Trying to get the `field_name` being deleted when viewing a route like `entity.field_config.user_field_delete_form`.

Example path: `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields/user.user.field_name/delete`

Some Hooks I've tried:

1. `hook_preprocess_html()`
2. `hook_preprocess_page()`
3. `hook_preprocess_page_title()`
4. `hook_preprocess_form_field_config_delete_form_alter()`

But the best I have found is an argument `[%label] => Field Label`.

I have an array of `field_names` and want to check if the `field_name` being deleted matches one of the values.

The goal is to add a custom `\Drupal::messenger()->addWanrning($warning);`.

This would be altering an *existing* delete form/page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `hook_form_alter` something like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MyModule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "field_config_delete_form"){
    $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning("You are going to delete field : " . $field->getName());
  }
 }
```